is there a way wake up my android app daily at 12 to run a bit of code
is there a way wake up my android app daily at 12 to run a bit of code like in alarm receiver but exactly at 12 mine runs late like 10min to hours
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        if (Calendar.getInstance().after(calendar)) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, new Intent(context, MyReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pendingIntent);

it is sometime running fine mostly not

Make sure to disable battery optimization for your app manually in Android settings.

You are using setInexactRepeating() and from it’s name it says it is inexact so the system can delay the alarm in order to achieve exact behavior you will have to use setAlamClock() and each time it fires at 12 you will have to schedule another one for the next time since there is no exact repeating one also you need to consider things like if the device reboots(all alarms are going to be cancelled) so a receiver to reschedule them will do the job.

how do i deal with a reboot then ?

When the device reboots the system sends an intent to all the apps and to listent to that i tent you need a broadcast receiver to be registered in your manifest and the action it listents to is the reboot one that is already provided by the os as i said
here is an article that explains broadcast receivers: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/broadcast-receiver-in-android-with-example/amp/
Also for more infos here is an article that deep dives in alarm manager: https://medium.com/@igordias/android-scheduling-alarms-with-precise-delivery-time-using-alarmmanager-75c409f3bde0
